# Can I use onesignal to trigger change order status automatically?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

Can I use Onesignal to send a notification of order changes to an Android device then if the user already opened the application on order's page/view the notification will be not shown but the order status on that page will be changed?

If yes, can I know the reference of documentation/tutor? If no, what are alternative ways to do it?

I have a project using Onesignal to send the notifications to the android devices. Currently just Simple notif, but my boss asked me to make the mobile app can auto change status order without user action. I'm a backend engineer, not an android dev so I don't know what really works of Onesignal in android. I just know Onesignal can be used to send the notification but what about data process after notification sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I understood: Your app has some kind of market or something from which people can order stuff. So, you want to know if OneSignal can send automated notifications as the order status changes?

If I have got it correct, my best guess will be, no. OneSignal can only manually send out notifications. The closest one can get with OneSignal to automations is scheduling notifications to be sent later. To achieve your purpose, your Android devs will probabaly have to write some code on their own and integrate it some way with the order status and all. Or else, your boss will have to appoint a few people who can track the order of the people and manually send out notifications to them using OneSignal (but, identifying the correct device might not be so easy).

That's my guess. But, OneSignal's support team is pretty nice. They might take a few days to answer, but, it's worth asking them if they can help your developers integrate the order status and OneSignal's notifications in some way.